# Getting started with NODE.JS in windows x86

Tags: windows, node.js

Just getting started with node.js. I've a Windows PC. I went to nodejs.org and downloaded the nodejs.msi for Windows then, I saw a folder in programfilesx86.

How do i write and compile my helloworld program?

I guess, I have to use the command prompt. I even created a file hello.js but i don't know where it goes or how to execute it.

Any inputs on this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Go to the command prompt (> Run > cmd), which is the Windows terminal.

There type node -v to see if Node is responding ok (it should display the version installed).

After that navigate to the folder containing your 'hello world' example.

For ex if you hello.js is in C:\ then:

```
cd C:
node hello.js
```

That should work.

Comment: :It is not responding.what should i set in environment variable.

Comment: @user1051322: You'll need to include node's directory in your PATH variable, though I though the Windows installer took care of that.

Comment: Ed S. the latest .msi of Node takes care of that for you.

Comment: As of June 2012 the windows installer still has its rough edges: it requires you to restart your windows session for the PATH changes to take effect, it doesnt let you choose your installation directory, etc

Comment: As of 2013.11 the windows installer is much better - PATH changes are often (not always) available in the same shell. A number of npm packages require run-as-Administrator to install successfully, though.

Answer (score 2):

After restarting my system,this worked bcoz it is windows.In windows,you've to restart after installing any thing.

Comment: Thats a common misconception.  Usually if you know enough you don't need to reboot, restarting an application or service is enough.  Chances are good a service needed starting or the command prompt needed reopening due to environment variables needing to be picked up again.

Comment: @Phil Hannent:Which service should i restart?

Answer (score 0):

Alternative is to use IDE like Enide Studio http://sf.net/p/nodeclipse/

Instead of typing in command prompt, just right-click any .js file and select Run As -> Node application, see output in console View. All in one windows, no need switch between.
Integrated debugger and JSHint.